# "IN Clause" causing "is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having difficulty getting past this error message.

This query works:

```
declare
       @warehouseID int =-1,
       @type int=2, --0 = all; 1 = serial;2 = nonserial
       @LocationID int =0



SELECT Sum(Quantity) AS Quantity,
       WarehouseName,
       WarehouseID, 
       sil.Location,
       max(si.RecordID) as test,
       min(si.RecordID) as test2,
       -- (SELECT max(TransactionDate) from SS_Inventory_History sih2 where sih2.InventoryID in (SI.RecordID)  
       -- )
       -- as test4,
       (select       max(Case When Serial_Number>'' Then COALESCE(si.SoldDate,'') else sih.TransactionDate end ) AS SoldDate
              FROM SS_Inventory SI
                     JOIN SS_Inventory_Location SIL ON SIL.RecordID=SI.LocationID 
                     LEFT JOIN SS_Inventory_Warehouse SIW ON SIW.RecordID =SIL.WarehouseID
                     Join SS_Inventory_History sih on InventoryID =sih.RecordID and sih.configStage = 7
              WHERE 
                     SIL.WarehouseID = CASE WHEN @warehouseID = -1 THEN SIL.WarehouseID  ELSE @warehouseID  END 
                     AND SI.LocationID = CASE WHEN @LocationID = 0 THEN SI.LocationID ELSE @LocationID END
                     AND ((si.Quantity=0 and Serial_Number>'') or (Serial_Number=''))
                     and SIL.Active=1
                     AND (
                           (@type = 0 ) OR 
                           (@type = 1 AND Serial_Number > '') OR
                           (@type = 2 AND COALESCE(Serial_Number,'')='') 
                     )
                     )  AS SoldDate,
       max(si.ReceivedDate) AS ReceivedDate

FROM SS_Inventory SI
       JOIN SS_Inventory_Location SIL ON SIL.RecordID=SI.LocationID 
       LEFT JOIN SS_Inventory_Warehouse SIW ON SIW.RecordID =SIL.WarehouseID
       WHERE 
              SIL.WarehouseID = CASE WHEN @warehouseID = -1 THEN SIL.WarehouseID  ELSE @warehouseID  END 
              AND SI.LocationID = CASE WHEN @LocationID = 0 THEN SI.LocationID ELSE @LocationID END
              AND Quantity>0
              and SIL.Active=1
              AND (
                     (@type = 0 ) OR 
                     (@type = 1 AND Serial_Number > '') OR
                     (@type = 2 AND COALESCE(Serial_Number,'')='') 
              )
       GROUP BY WarehouseName,
              WarehouseID,
              Location, 
              Part_Number,
              Dist_Part_Num
```

but when i add/uncomment

```
       (SELECT max(TransactionDate) from SS_Inventory_History sih2 where sih2.InventoryID in (SI.RecordID)  
       )
       as test4,
```

so that it looks like

```
declare
       @warehouseID int =-1,
       @type int=2, --0 = all; 1 = serial;2 = nonserial
       @LocationID int =0



SELECT Sum(Quantity) AS Quantity,
       WarehouseName,
       WarehouseID, 
       sil.Location,
       --delete me?
       max(si.RecordID) as test,
       min(si.RecordID) as test2,
       (SELECT max(TransactionDate) from SS_Inventory_History sih2 where sih2.InventoryID in (SI.RecordID)  
       )
       as test4,
       (select       max(Case When Serial_Number>'' Then COALESCE(si.SoldDate,'') else sih.TransactionDate end ) AS SoldDate
              FROM SS_Inventory SI
                     JOIN SS_Inventory_Location SIL ON SIL.RecordID=SI.LocationID 
                     LEFT JOIN SS_Inventory_Warehouse SIW ON SIW.RecordID =SIL.WarehouseID
                     Join SS_Inventory_History sih on InventoryID =sih.RecordID and sih.configStage = 7
              WHERE 
                     SIL.WarehouseID = CASE WHEN @warehouseID = -1 THEN SIL.WarehouseID  ELSE @warehouseID  END 
                     AND SI.LocationID = CASE WHEN @LocationID = 0 THEN SI.LocationID ELSE @LocationID END
                     AND ((si.Quantity=0 and Serial_Number>'') or (Serial_Number=''))
                     and SIL.Active=1
                     AND (
                           (@type = 0 ) OR 
                           (@type = 1 AND Serial_Number > '') OR
                           (@type = 2 AND COALESCE(Serial_Number,'')='') 
                     )
                     )  AS SoldDate,
       max(si.ReceivedDate) AS ReceivedDate

FROM SS_Inventory SI
       JOIN SS_Inventory_Location SIL ON SIL.RecordID=SI.LocationID 
       LEFT JOIN SS_Inventory_Warehouse SIW ON SIW.RecordID =SIL.WarehouseID
       WHERE 
              SIL.WarehouseID = CASE WHEN @warehouseID = -1 THEN SIL.WarehouseID  ELSE @warehouseID  END 
              AND SI.LocationID = CASE WHEN @LocationID = 0 THEN SI.LocationID ELSE @LocationID END
              AND Quantity>0
              and SIL.Active=1
              AND (
                     (@type = 0 ) OR 
                     (@type = 1 AND Serial_Number > '') OR
                     (@type = 2 AND COALESCE(Serial_Number,'')='') 
              )
       GROUP BY WarehouseName,
              WarehouseID,
              Location, 
              Part_Number,
              Dist_Part_Num
```

I get this error message:
Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 15
Column 'SS_Inventory.RecordID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: LEFT JOIN the subquery instead.

Comment: Thanks, I think I was able to do it using that method

Comment: Basic formatting would help. This query is unreadable